# Fabry-Perot interferometer using Airy function in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to plot T(transmission) and R(reflection) coefficients. I am new at Mathematica, so please excuse possible crude errors. This is my code:

[image]

The output gives just an empty animation window. It seems as a straightforward thing to me, in which I am making a trivial mistake. Any help?

Code:

```
δ[Subscript[n, f] _, d_, Subscript[θ, 3] _, λ_] := (4*Pi)/λ*
    Subscript[n, f]*d*cos (Subscript[θ, 3]) 

R[δ_] := Nsolve [R == (4*R *(sin (δ[Subscript[θ, 3], Subscript[n, f], 
   d, λ]/2)^2))/((1 - R)^2 + 4*R*(sin (δ[Subscript[θ, 3], Subscript[n, f],  
   d, λ]/2)^2)) , R]

T[δ_] := Nsolve [T == (1 - R)^2/((1 - R)^2 + 
     4*R*(sin (δ[Subscript[θ, 3], Subscript[n, f], d, λ]/2)^2)), T]

Manipulate[Plot[{R1[δ], T1[δ]}, {Subscript[Θ, 3], -(Pi/2), Pi/2}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.004], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
    {Thickness[0.004], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1} {0, 1}}, PlotLegends -> {"T", "R"} ], 
    {{λ, 500*10^-9, "wavelength λ"}, 400*10^-9, 800*10^-9}, 
    {{d, 5*10^-6, "thickness d"}, 2*10^-6, 10*10^-6}, 
    {{n, 1.5, "refractive index n"}, 1.33, 2}]
```

Comment: Please provide your code in Mathematica format, so that readers can copy and run it.  Images are of little value.  By the way, `δ` appears to be undefined.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I added a code, though it looks messy. 

Could you please tell me how can I define δ? I thought that in the first line i defined it, and then used it in line 2 and 3 as a variable.

Comment: There are many syntax issues: (1) `Nsolve` should be `NSolve`, as hinted by the fact that it is in blue (pay attention to the syntax coloring!) (2) You cannot use subscripted symbols as arguments to functions. *Mathematica* interprets `Subscript[θ,3] _` as 1Subscript[θ,3]`  *times* `_`. *Don't use subscripts in *Mathematica*, especially as a new user.*

Comment: Please disregard my comment that `δ` appears to be undefined.  Now that I have seen your code, I see that it is defined.  However, as @march just stated, do not use `Subscript` without a compelling reason.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed theta and n, and NSolve command. Also, I see that R and T are R1 and T1 in plot command, so i fixed that too. However, still no results. 

edit: I also fixed wrong parenthesis for sin and cos.

Comment: `sin(...)` and `cos(...)` should be `Sin[...]` and `Cos[...]`.  Also, read the documentation for `NSolve` to see the form in which it presents results.

Comment: Yes, I fixed sin and cos. 
So, R is a function of δ. But this equation is given in implicit form. What would you use to get R[δ_] from this equation?  
T is a function of both δ and R. Can I then simply write T[R_, δ_]:= ... 
edit: I am reading NSolve documentation, can't find the way yet.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to everything in one go without much (if any) knowledge of MMA or its syntax. I would recommend building your problem, and you skill up more slowly. Can you use in-built functions - getting Sin[a number] etc, next can you define and execute your own functions correctly, next can you Plot (without a manipulate), next can you extract results from NSolve etc. Do each step individually and then with that skill and knowledge you should be able to understand how to put it all together.

Comment: There are just so many errors in your code, I can believe any one bit of it ever worked on its own. As others have pointed out: capitolisation of in-built function names, use of parentheses and square brackets, order of arguements, subscripted arguements, you define for R and T then call R1 and T1.... Passing a function name as an arguement

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there are a myriad of syntax errors in your question, some of which have already been pointed out by myself and others. I reiterate my above suggestion of building code up carefully and checking it works at each step.

I believe there is also a physical misunderstanding in your code. You do not need to solve for the the reflection and transmission coefficients which I shall label `r` and `t` respectively. The `R` inside your `NSolve`s is not the reflection coefficient but rather the average reflectance of the surfaces in the interferometer which is as much a constant in your situation as `d`, `n`, or `lambda`. Hopefully [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry%E2%80%93P%C3%A9rot_interferometer#Theory) can make this more clear.

Thus I believe your code should look more like:
[image]

which should provide you with a solution looking like:
[image]

I have not pasted code (yet) because I believe it will be a useful exercise for you to modify your own code thus identifying the syntax errors and enabling you to further modify things should you so wish.

Hope this is what you were after. Like I've said, try building things up piece by piece to get an understanding of how they work and where they go wrong!

Comment: I studied some more about it, and I understood a physical mistake. I fixed the code, but I still get "Incomplete expression; more input is needed ." error. Any help?

Comment: New code: 
\[Delta][n_, d_, \[Theta]_, \[Lambda]_] := 
 4 Pi*n*d*Cos[\[Theta]]/\[Lambda] 
\[Theta]1[n_] := 2 ArcSin[Sqrt[n*n - 1]] 

R[n_, \[Theta]_, \[Theta]1_] := (n*Cos[\[Theta]1] - 
    Cos[\[Theta]])/(n*Cos[\[Theta]1] + Cos[\[Theta]])

E[R_, \[Delta]_] := (4 R 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\((Sin[\[Delta]/2])\), \(^\)]\) 2)/((1 - R)^2 + 
  4 R (Sin[\[Delta]/2])^2)


D[R_, \[Delta]_] := (
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\((1 - R)\), \(^\)]\) 2)/((1 - R)^2 + 
  4 R (Sin[\[Delta]/2])^2)

Comment: Second part of code: 
Manipulate[
 Plot[{E[\[Delta][n, d, \[Theta], \[Lambda]], 
    R[n, \[Theta], \[Theta]1[n]]], 
   D[\[Delta][n, d, \[Theta], \[Lambda]], 
    R[n, \[Theta], \[Theta]1[n]]]}, {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.004], 
     RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {Thickness[0.004], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1} {0, 1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"R", "T"} ], {{\[Lambda], 500*10^-9, 
   "wavelength \[Lambda]"}, 350*10^-9, 
  370*10^-9}, {{d, 5*10^-6, "thickness d"}, 2*10^-6, 
  10*10^-6}, {{n, 1.5, "refractive index n"}, 1.33, 1.8}]`

Comment: Heh, I'm afraid I don't stand a chance of unravelling that lot! Take a screenshot perhaps and post the link here?

Comment: I don't see how to upload directly in comment, so here is the link to a screenshot. 
http://imgur.com/f9mNGDy